# IPv4 Variable Length Subnetting vs Fixed Length Subnetting?

Tags: ip, ipv4, subnet

I'm trying to understand the difference between variable length subnetting and fixed length subnetting, from what I know variable length subnetting will create different subnet masks depending on the subnet.

But in fixed length subnetting, the supernet mask is calculated by 32 - (host_bits + subent_bits).

So if the host_bits are going to be changing depending on the subnet, then wouldn't the supernet mask change as well?

Comment: Variable length means you can divide a given network into several subnets of different sizes. Fixed length means a given network is divided into several subnets of the same size.

Answer (score 0):

Subnets and supernets are just a matter of perspective.

Whether you split a network in four equal parts or in one half and two quarters, the technique is the same: you move the division between network part and host part further right and the bits you add to the network part let you address subnets.

E.g.

```
10.10.16.0/20 = 10.10.16.0 to 10.10.23.255
=>
10.10.16.0/22 = 10.10.16.0 to 10.10.19.255
&
10.10.20.0/23 = 10.10.20.0 to 10.10.21.255
&
10.10.22.0/23 = 10.10.22.0 to 10.10.23.255
```

Supernetting works the same, only in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the variable mask and the fixed mask is the versatility, in the fixed mask you can only make subnets of a single size and this is a great restriction since you waste too many ips, instead with the variable mask it allows us to create the networks of the size that we want, thus being able to waste the least amount of ips possible, thus making network schemes more efficient.